# Blender 2.80 Subsurf option to display wireframe in edit mo

Tags: modifiers

The wireframe in edit mode went missing after hiding vertices, with subsrf modifier. In 2.79 it still show the wireframe even the vertices are hidden.

Is there a way to fix this in 2.80?

[image: Blender 2.79 and 2.80 Subsurf edit mode and hiding vertices]